# Parse 'Cannot sign up without a password.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

For some reason, sign up is failing in my Parse registration implementation.

The error seems obvious:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot sign up without a password.'
```

But I have tried setting a password from a UITextField, explicitly setting a password, and no matter what registration fails with the same error. I've also loggged the user's password before submitting to ensure it's set, and it does log.

I'm using code almost directly out of the Parse documentation:

```
PFUser* user = [PFUser user];
user.email = self.emailText.text;
user.username = self.emailText.text;
user.password = self.passwordText.text;
NSLog(@"Pword: %@", user.password);
[user setObject:self.firstNameText.text forKey:@"firstName"];
[user setObject:self.lastNameText.text forKey:@"lastName"];
[user setObject:@"customer" forKey:@"userType"];
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    if(!error && succeeded){
        [self goToProfileSelection];
    } else {
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];

        UIAlertView* usernameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Logging In" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [usernameAlert show];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Did you try without the 3 `setObject` lines after your `NSLog`? Other than that, your code seems perfectly valid to me.

Comment: yeah, not sure if you need to save the plain user and then add your custom data once the save has completed...

Comment: I took out those custom data assignments, and it still seems to crash.

Comment: It seems to have been related to subclassing the User model - I wasn't able to fix it while including the User model (and don't have time to do so at the moment) but once I removed `[User registerSubclass];`, it started to work.

Comment: Note that I did try a version that used the PFUser subclass explicitly, but this also did not work